# how to best intialize and store constant objects?

Tags: c++

I'm unexperienced with C++ coming from other OOP languages.

Looking for a way to initialize constant objects, let's say I have this simple vector:

```
Vector3D UP = Vector3D(0,1,0);
```

and I would like to reuse the object behind the `UP` variable.

for example in Java you would make it a static field inside some class:

```
class Constants {
  public static final Vector3D UP = new Vector3D(0,1,0);
}
```

and can access it like this:

```
Vector3D up = Constants.UP;
```

How, in C++, do I safely tell it to initialize that object once and then have it immutably accessible anywhere I include the header?

I've read that static initialization is potentially very bad in C++ because the compilation order is nondeterministic and if you're having dependencies between different constants you could end up with undefined initialization state if they're not in the same compilation unit.

Comment: Have a look at [constexpr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr)

Comment: played around with that and then got stuck up trying to figure out what LiteralType is...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If `Vector3D` is a simple enough class, a [literal type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/LiteralType), for which you may define a [`constexpr` constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr), then the most straightforward way is likely to define it in a header as follows:

```
namespace Constants {
  constexpr Vector3D UP(0,1,0);
}
```

This makes is a true compile time constant, so it will likely occupy no storage (depends on how you use it). If it does end up occupying storage, then the `constexpr` specifier implies internal linkage. Every translation unit that needs the constant to have storage has its own copy of the constant. So you don't run afoul of the static initialization order fiasco (inside a single TU, declaration order of namespace scope static objects dictates initialization order).

Since C++17, those multiple definitions can be condensed into one with the help of the [`inline` specifier](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/inline). The one true constant will look like this:

```
namespace Constants {
  inline constexpr Vector3D UP(0,1,0);
}
```

Comment: looks good, but now I'm wrestling to find out why that class isn't a literal type and why it doesn't accept my constexpr constructor... is it sufficient to declare `constexpr Vector3D(double x, double y, double z);`?

Comment: @Jakob - Declaring it as such is the first step. If the compiler tries to evaluate the class as a constant and fails (because the c'tor body/class aren't meeting the criteria), it will complain.

Comment: @Jakob you also have to *omit* `~Vector3D`, but you probably already do

Comment: thanks.. turns out the compiler didn't like the bad constructor syntax I was using. working now, cool!

Comment: @StoryTeller for pre c++17, why not `static constexpr`?

Comment: @Moia - Because the `static` is superfluous. The `constexpr` already implies it anyway.

Comment: @StoryTeller didn't know it, thanks! Even with c++11?

Comment: @Moia - Even with C++03. Namespace scoped `const` objects are with internal linkage unless explicitly made `extern`. It's the `const` implied by `constexpr` that makes things have internal linkage.